# Plotting two points with same abscissa

Tags: plotting

I want to make a ListPlot with the following data:

```
data={{1, 0.167587}, {8, 3.2431}, {11, 3.90236}, {20,5.44598}, {31, {10.3562, 2.06495}}, {36, {11.3706,2.08124}}, {45, {12.9578, 2.08648}}, {61, {14.195, 2.1608}}};
```

However, as you can see, some points are in the form p1={x,y} and some others in the form p2={x,{y1,y2}}. For p1, obviously, I would like to see a point at {x,y}. For p2, I would like to have two points plotted, one at {x,y1} and one at {x,y2}.
How to?

thanks!

Comment: `newData=Map[Sequence @@ 
    If[ListQ[#[[2]]], 
     Flatten[Outer[List, {#[[1]]}, #[[2]]], 1], {#}] &]@dat` and then `ListPlot@newData`.

Comment: A replacement rule like `{x_, l_List} :> Apply[Sequence, {x, #} & /@ l]` ought to be useful.

Comment: both these suggestions work well. thanks